well-defined configurations of heavy elements
For heavy elements, the energy difference between the outer levels is small, and degeneracy of the levels are high (especially for f electrons).
Therefore, is it still meaningful to say the electrons take a specific configuration?
For example, the configuration of gold is  [Xe] $6s^{1} 4f^{14} 5d^{10}$ according the literature.
But how pure is it? What is the portion of  [Xe] $6s^{2} 4f^{13}5d^{10} $?


Therefore, is it still meaningful to say the electrons take a specific configuration?

It's perfectly meaningful. In quantum mechanics a system can have only well-defined states, and lower atomic energy levels even for heaviest known element do not form continuum.

But how pure is it?

That's a different question, that can boils down: how much atoms are in particular state.
Note: the considerations below assumes isolated atoms. For non-isolated atoms idea of electron configuration is ill-defined and one should use electron states of the whole molecule or use some collective treatment like band model for crystalline solids. The approach would be somewhat similar, though.
First, we shall recall from statistical physics that population of an energy level is proportional to $A \exp(-E/kT)$ where $A$ is degeneracy degree of the level, i.e. number of microstates corresponding to this level, energy is in joules, k is Boltsman constrant and T is in Kelvin scale. To get an actual percentage, one has to normalize using sum of population factors of all levels. IIRC, electron term can be separated from kinetic terms, so for our purposes we can ignore movement of atoms and consider only electron part, that is, energy states of an atom. If we do, we need data on energy data of different states of an atom and their degeneracy.
For atom levels we can use NIST Atomic Spectra Database Levels (1). Note, that it uses astronimy spectroscopic convention, i.e. neutral atom of gold would be denoted as $\ce{Au I}$, a positive ion would be denoted as $\ce{Au II}$ and so forth. IIRC, for degeneracy we can use value in the J column multiplied by two. Note, that for same electron configuration, say $\ce{Au I}\ \  5d^96s^2$, you can have several energy levels with different degeneracy, in this particular case 2 levels with degeneracy 1(non-degenerate) and 3.
This assumes that the system is in equilibrium, in particular there is an thermodynamic equilibrium with photon gas present in the system. In practice photons can leave or enter considered system and the question becomes a problem of rather complicated kinetics with many extra parameters required to consider and no simple solutions.
Homework: find on the web translation formula from $cm^{-1}$ energy scale (used in the NIST database) into $J$ energy scale and calculate ratio of population factors for ground stat and a few lower states for $\ce{Li}$ atom at 1000 $K$.
(1) https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html

I think you did not understand my question. I mean the extra ground state of an isolated atom should be a superposition of many different configurations, and likely for heavy atoms, there is no dominant configuration.

If you consider mixing of extra orbitals into motion of electrons in multi-electron atoms, it starts at helium. "Classical" orbitals are obtained for hydrogen-like atoms with no electron-electron interaction. The moment you introduce second electron, the situation becomes really complicated and the electron configuration is merely an approximation. It works reasonably well for all elements up to Bi at least, where it really should fall apart due to relativistic effects, but still works.
